# How to keep track of line number of big files which spans across multiple nodes?

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading big file using sc.textFile(file) here file is big file which spans across multiple nodes. I need the line number for my debugging and index purpose.

here as my file is divided in each node the line starts with 1 but it should be total line number from previous node +1 .

please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

> Block quoteYou can use sc.textFile().zipWithIndex() which will add index to the file so you can track the line number 
>   Block quote